# Algorithm to minimise boxes and maximise objects

Tags: algorithm

A box contains 3 numeric attributes. The attributes are maximum **total** (normal+rare) objects, maximum **normal** objects, maximum **rare** objects. Now let's say for example, I have 4 boxes.

- Box 1: 5 max total objects, 4 max normal objects, 2 max rare objects.
- Box 2: 10 max total, 9 max normal, 3 max rare.
- Box 3: 8 max total, 5 max normal, 4 max rare.
- Box 4: 4 max total, 4 max normal, 1 max rare.

Now I have to put **8 normal objects and 5 rare objects** into these boxes.

What is the minimum amount of boxes I could use and what boxes are they? Programmatically, I could achieve this via brute-force/recursive searching. After finding out all the possible box combinations, I would sort the array/list according to the least amount of space wasted in the box. Is there a more programmatically efficient or mathematical way of finding out the minimum amount of boxes to be used?

Comment: What is the objective? Minimum boxes or minimum "wasted space"?

Comment: Both actually, I am thinking of returning a list of box combinations. Traverse through this list to find the minimum "wasted space" of these boxes. However, the primary objective is to find the minimum boxes. (To answer your question)

Comment: A deterministic algorithm needs a specific goal. You must decide what that goal is.

Comment: First of all define the optimization goal as a function of number of boxes and wasted space then try to optimize this function

Comment: I think this is a hard problem. [The bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: @wallyk: I disagree. Stackoverflow is also for ["a software algorithm"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @AndyG:  fine, retracted.

Comment: Ive decided to use novice algorithm with a little tweak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One efficient way I think is:
Let's say you have "n" boxes, and "a" normal objects and "b" rare objects and a>b.

1. Sort all the boxes in a list according to the attribute maximum space in normal objects. Call this list `X`.
2. Sort all the boxes in another list according to attribute max. Space in rare objects. Call this list `Y`.
3. Since `a>b`, fill the largest box in list `X`.
4. Check if `a` (remaining) > `b` (remaining), if yes put them in the next largest box in list `X`, else put them in next largest box in list `Y` (if the box filled was also the largest box in list `Y`).
5. Keep on doing so till both `a` and `b` are `0`.

This would not always give you the exact minimum number of boxes for all the cases though, but will work generally quite well with large numbers of boxes.

Comment: No problem - click on the "edited x time ago" link to see how I formatted it. It's easy when you get the hang of it.

Comment: This is a great algorithm! Thank you

Comment: Ops sorry didnt see your comment. Alright i wanted the algorithm to give me the least amount of "wasted space" right? What i did was sort the list according to the smallest gap between the "a" and maximum space available. Same goes for "b". For example, referring to the example i posted, 8 max normal objects in box 3. And i have to put 8 normal boxes right? So when sorting `8 - 8 = 0`. 0 will be at the top of the list (ie, difference beween "a" and max)